# crop paper size to image size

Tags: margins, standalone

I want a pdf file cropped to image size (modelo1.png) but top margin still there.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=9cm, height=9cm,top=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document} 
        \begin{picture}(270,300) 
        \put(-0.5,0.5){\includegraphics[width=9cm,height=9cm]{documentos/modelo1.png}} 
        \put(180,15){\Large F000939} 
        \end{picture} 
\end{document}
```

How Can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`picture` environment was higher than image, thus white space at the top. Adjust size of `picture` environment to be the same as image:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 
        \begin{picture}(257,256) 
        \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=9cm,height=9cm]{example-image}} 
        \put(180,15){\Large F000939} 
        \end{picture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AndreyVinajera My pleasure!